# Vue.component() dynamic import with loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to import dynamically a component with a Loader default if it's not loaded ?

We use something like this right now,

```js
import Dashboard from '../components/dashboard';


Vue.component('dashboard', Dashboard);
```

I tried something like this as the documentation say [link to the docs](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Manejo-del-estado-de-carga)

```js
import Loader from '../components/loader';
const Dashboard = () => ({
  component: import('../components/dashboard'),
  loading: Loader,
  delay: 500, //to test
})

Vue.component('dashboard', Dashboard);
```

Either way it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *should* already work. It might seem to not work because the loading happens instantaneously.

If you artificially delay the return of `import('../components/dashboard')`, you'll notice the loader displayed:

```js
const delayed = async (promise) => {
  const result = await promise
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))
  return result
}

Vue.component('Dashboard', () => ({
  component: delayed(import('./components/Dashboard.vue')),
  loading: Loader,
  delay: 500
}))
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-global-component-in-vue-07foy?file=/src/main.js)

Realistically, the dynamic component is intended for components that might take a significant amount of time to load (e.g., from a remote URL).